# How get the abbreviated name of the day of the week in Dart

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart

Somebody knows how can I extract from DateTime the abbreviated name of the day of the week?

ej:

```dart
DateTime date = DateTime.now();
String dateFormat = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm').format(date);
```

Result -> Fri

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use 'E' as a date pattern (ABBR_WEEKDAY pattern)

```dart
DateFormat(DateFormat.ABBR_WEEKDAY).format(date);
```

Check this for more info: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html